# Controlling links in Leaflet markers

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers

How to make Leaflet markers go to unique link? Currently marker.on near the bottom gets the same link for each marker. I would like it to assign the corresponding link from var data for each. Cannot change the formatting too much as it links to other javascript pages as well

```
//sample data values for populate map
var data = [
    {"loc":[43.0680798,-89.4083302], "title":"Jordan's Big Ten Pub", "link":"Jordans_Big_Ten_Pub.html", "nid":"0"},
            {"loc":[43.0678893,-89.4064022], "title":"The Red Zone Madison", "link":"The_Red_Zone_Madison.html", "nid":"1"},
            {"loc":[43.0747636,-89.38156], "title":"Tipsy Cow", "link":"Tipsy_Cow.html", "nid":"52"}
];

var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 14, center: new L.latLng(43.072, -89.39) });  //set center from first location

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));    //base layer
var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
    position:'topright',        
    layer: markersLayer,
    initial: false,
    zoom: 19,
    marker: false
});

map.addControl( controlSearch );

////////////populate map with markers from sample data
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
        loc = data[i].loc,
        j=data[i].nid,      //position found
        marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title}, {win_url: data[i].link } );//se property searched
    marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title  );
    **marker.on('click', function(){window.location=(data[j].link)});**
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please do not just post code. This is known as a "wall of code" post, and generally garners downvotes and close votes. Also, question quality is generally improved by writing out the full Question, then doubling back to write a title that describes the subject of the post. I took the liberty of transferring the on text to the body and making up a new title. Please take the opportunity to [Edit] the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with your custom option `win_url`, but option must not be declared as a separate object, it has to be declared together with standard options. Code could then look something like this:

```
for (i in data) {
  var title = data[i].title,
    loc = data[i].loc,
    j=data[i].nid,
    marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {
      title: title,
      win_url: data[i].link
    });
  marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title  );
  marker.on('click', function(evt){
    window.location = evt.target.options.win_url;
  });
  markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}
```